# Given P(Y | X) and random samples of Y drawn from P(Y), can one probabilistically assign values of X to each Y?

Tags: conditional-probability, random-generation

Say I have a set of Y values drawn randomly from P(Y).  I'd like to probabilistically assign a value of X to each Y.  However, I don't know P(X|Y), but I do know P(Y|X).  Bayes' theorem relates these two conditional probabilities, but directly implementing Bayes would require knowledge of P(X) which I don't know a priori.

Any ideas?  Seems like this should be possible...

Comment: You need to know 3 out of 4, of have a system of 2 equations or some other constraint. Are you saying you only know 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most concretely without knowledge of $P(X|Y)$ or $P(X)$ you can not get at $P(X|Y)$.  To be precise one could construct distinct joint distributions $P(X,Y)$ and $Q(X,Y)$ such that $P(Y)=Q(Y)$ and $P(Y|X) = Q(Y|X)$ but $P(X) \neq Q(X)$ and $P(X|Y) \neq Q(X|Y)$.

At this point your best bet is perhaps to make assumptions about $P(X)$.  For example if you assume the (possibly improper) uniform distribution on $P(X)$ then sampling with probabilities proportional to $P(Y|X)$ is equivalent to sampling from $P(X|Y)$.

You can make other assumptions about $P(X)$ and follow these to consequences for $P(Y|X)$.  I'm not sure if you have access to any samples from $P(X)$ or any feedback about the $(x,y)$ pairs that you generate, but these could help inform the process.

Comment: This is very helpful.  I was considering an iterative process: (1) assume uniform P(X), (2) use Bayes to generate X samples, (3) update estimate of P(X) based on distribution of X from step 2, (4) goto step 2.  Does this make sense?

Comment: The big question is, what exactly do you mean by "update estimate of P(X)"?

Comment: What I had in mind was estimating P(X) by taking the histogram of the X values from step 2.  There are problems with this approach: I could, for instance, end up setting the P(X) to 0 when really it should just be small.  This error would then propagate back to step 2.  Maybe this is just a bad idea...

Comment: You could try doing it by averaging normal distributions.  For example after the n^th iteration you would approximate P(X) as $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i \mathcal{N}(x_i, h(n))$.  This is known as kernel density estimation, but is typically done with actual samples from the distribution.  I can not speak to the efficacy of doing it in this iterative fashion.  $h(n)$ is called the bandwidth and should start large and decrease with $n$.